# Elegant way of arranging items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the fiddle I'm working with:
http://jsfiddle.net/g2Zus/

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">
        <div id="cityList" class="inner-table"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <div id="cityList2" class="inner-table"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
         <div id="cityList3" class="inner-table"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to elegantly arrange(explanation like how is given in second point) them (like not fixing the number of columns as I did in this example).
2. If 'n' be the number of elements in the array(assuming the number is not fixed) and if n is an even number divide the screen such that it has same number of elements in all the rows and if n is odd the extra element can occupy the entire last row.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) instead of hacking together something like this.

Comment: I did not understand that Masonry can you please elaborate on that. I'm sorry but I'm new to javascript and jQuery

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/